# Rails Actionmailer Handling of Failed Messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer, behavior

I'm using rails 2.2.2 on a linux box and am using a rake task to send some emails.  It's a very simple script without error handling:

1.) Get emails to send
2.) Send email
3.) Mark emails as sent

Right now, the port on the smtp server has been blocked temporarily so steps 1 and 3 are completing but not step 2.  My question is, when I unblock the port, are the messages that previously failed queued somewhere (and are going to be sent) or did they timeout and get /dev/nulled? If they are queued up somewhere, can I get the file location?  I just want to understand the behavior so I can build out appropriate error handling.  Thanks,

Drew